# Sharing code between ASP.NET MVC project and Cordova project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, cordova, minify

I am developing a Cordova based mobile app via Visual Studio's Cordova template as well as an ASP.NET MVC web application in the same Visual Studio solution.  I'd like to be able to share as much HTML between both projects as possible.  One issue I am running into is the bundling and minification that takes place in ASP.NET that is not available in the Cordova project.  Any ideas how I could support minification within Visual Studio across both projects that would allow me to share as much code as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova's project file `.jsproj` is an ordinary build file that is handled by MSBuild, so you can apply whatever processing logic you need by adding custom targets. You can even run tools from Node.js world like Grunt or Gulp by installing respective VS extensions.

As to sharing code between ASP.NET and Cordova projects, I suggest adding links in your .jsproj, as follows:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetProject>C:\YourAspNetProject</AspNetProject>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(AspNetProject)\Views\**\*.cshtml">
    <Link>views\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName).html</Link>
  </Content>
  <!-- add other links here -->
</ItemGroup>
```

This way VS displays the linked files in Solution Explorer and allow you to edit them as if they were local.

Unfortunately, the current version of VS Tools for Apache Cordova, CTP3, does not support linked items, so another change has to be made in your .jsproj:

```xml
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>PreBuild;$(BuildDependsOn)</BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PreBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <LinkedFiles Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
    <!-- add other links here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(LinkedFiles.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(LinkedFiles.Link)" />
</Target>
```

The `PreBuild` task is called before any `Build` subtask and copies the linked files to your Cordova's project. The rest of the build process runs as usual.

Comment: Tried adding the PropertyGroup and ItemGroup stuff to my `.jsproj` for a single JS file I want to share. When the project reloads the link appears briefly before disappearing. Using VS 2015 Update 2. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @phuzi sorry, I have never dealt with VS 2015 Update 2.